Spring Upgrade from 5.3 to 6. PatternParseException in XML based configuration
I'm trying to upgrade my Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux application (which uses XML-based configurations) from Spring 5.3 to Spring 6.1.14. Below is a section of my security.xml configuration:
<security:http request-matcher="mvc" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="lmmsAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied.html?_flowId=accessDenied-flow"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.gif" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.png" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html?_flowId=login-flow" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.html?_flowId=logout-flow" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.html?_flowId=accessDenied-flow" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/postlogin" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/safeLogin" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/homepage.html" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ajax/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/configuration.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_1') or hasRole('ROLE_2') or hasRole('ROLE_3')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/inventory.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_4') or hasRole('ROLE_5') or hasRole('ROLE_6')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/report.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_1') or hasRole('ROLE_2') or hasRole('ROLE_3') or hasRole('ROLE_4') or hasRole('ROLE_5') or hasRole('ROLE_6')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminInventory.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_1') or hasRole('ROLE_2') or hasRole('ROLE_3')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/testing.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_1')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/myRequests.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_4') or hasRole('ROLE_5') or hasRole('ROLE_6')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/otherUserSearchInventory.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_4') or hasRole('ROLE_5') or hasRole('ROLE_6')" />
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/logout.html?_flowId=logout-flow"/>
    <security:request-cache ref="nullRequestCache" />
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="lmmsAuthenticationProcessingFilter" />
    <security:logout success-handler-ref="lmmsLogoutCustomHandler" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <security:csrf />
    <security:headers defaults-disabled="true">
        <security:hsts />
        <security:cache-control />
        <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://code.jquery.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
    </security:headers>
</security:http>

When I navigate to the base URL of the application, it redirects to index.jsp, then to login.html, and then triggers the manual flow. Ideally, it should load the login page, but instead, I receive the following error:
09:40:59,329 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /lmms/logout.html: org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.util.pattern.InternalPathPatternParser.peekDoubleWildcard(InternalPathPatternParser.java:250)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.util.pattern.InternalPathPatternParser.parse(InternalPathPatternParser.java:113)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser.parse(PathPatternParser.java:129)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.lambda$match$0(PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.java:64)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.match(PathPatternMatchableHandlerMapping.java:62)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector$LookupPathMatchableHandlerMapping.match(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:548)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher.matcher(MvcRequestMatcher.java:95)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:76)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:45)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:95)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at deployment.lmms.war//sg.edu.nus.lmms.common.security.LmmsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(LmmsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:68)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:362)
        at deployment.lmms.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:278)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.0.GA-redhat-00011//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
        at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.12.SP2-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Steps I have tried to resolve the issue:
Set the property spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher, but this didn't solve the problem.
Changed the pattern in XML from:
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.gif" access="permitAll" />

to:
<security:intercept-url pattern="/*.gif" access="permitAll" />

Tried the answers from other questions facing the same exception (example), but they didn't work.
Changed request-matcher="ant", but this also didn't work.
All of these attempts still result in the redirection issue.
We currently don't want to completely switch to annotation-based configuration due to the complexity of the code and the tight timeline of the project but this may be an option in the future.
Has anyone encountered this issue when upgrading Spring to 6.1.14 for an XML based Spring MVC application? How can I resolve this?
